# Download button is not working in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form that generates some records like following image -->
[prime faces datatable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jtdg.png).

Each row has a download button and it generates a unique file.
I want to download a file from each row data in download button.

When I clicked on the first row's download button, one file downloaded. Next i clicked on the second row download button, but it downloads the first row file again.

I am getting same file for every row's download button.

my code:

**xhtml page:**

```
<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Download" />
  </f:facet>
  <p:commandButton  value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#   {sBean.prepDownload}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{sBean.download}"/>
  </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

**Bean class:**

```
StudentReportPojo info = null;
if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {

    for(StudentReportPojo aa:list){
        filepath=aa.getPath();
        System.out.println("file path of file "+filepath);
        //prepDownload(filepath);
    }

}
private  DefaultStreamedContent download;

public void setDownload(DefaultStreamedContent download) {
    this.download = download;
}

public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("GET = " + download.getName());
    return download;
}

public void prepDownload() throws Exception {

        File file = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                        .getExternalContext();
        setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input,
                        externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
        System.out.println("PREP = " + download.getName());

}
```

Please give me your suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a bit of time and format your code properly. It makes it easier for us to read

Comment: And read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [mcve]

Comment: i see ***nothing*** in `prepDownload` actionListener or `getDownload` to believe that you have any logic to download a different file in each row. HInt: Pass *something* to action or actionListener or the value attiribute of `<p:fileDownload>` so that another file can get downloaded. E.g. pass `filepath` to ActionListener like `#{sBean.prepDownload(datatableVarAttribute)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do I see in your code that you are not passing instance path for particular row to `prepDownload()` Method so you need to do modify datatable like pass path value to `prepDownload(dt.path)` Method. I'm assuming here dt is datatable variable and path is variable which is store in your datatable as `getList()`

```
  <p:dataTable var="dt" value="#{managedBean.getList()}">
       .
       //put your rest code...
       .
       <p:column>
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Download" />
          </f:facet>
          <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#{sBean.prepDownload(dt.path)}">
              <p:fileDownload value="#{sBean.download}"/>
          </p:commandButton>
      </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

and you need to change `prepDownload() method` to `prepDownload(String instancepath)`  in bean class like:

```
public void prepDownload(String instancepath) throws Exception {    
        File file = new File(instancepath); //here passing instance path
        .
        .
        //rest of code need to put same...
        .
        . 
}
```

I tried this it is working for me.